# Docker giving Connection refused when accessing service through gateway

Tags: docker, docker-compose, microservices, api-gateway

I have a microservice project that works well without docker. I'm using react as a front-end and spring boot as the backend. In the front end I make a post using localhost:9191/images/test/all. 9191 is where my gateway is and then it redirects to the images microservice that is located in 9001. When looking at the gateway logs in docker it gives me this error:

```
2021-05-10 12:14:27.002 ERROR 1 --- [or-http-epoll-4] a.w.r.e.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler : [dca16fe0-1] 500 Server Error for HTTP GET "/images/test/all"

io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: finishConnect(..) failed: Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:9001

Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException:

Error has been observed at the following site(s):

|_ checkpoint ⇢ springfox.boot.starter.autoconfigure.SwaggerUiWebFluxConfiguration$CustomWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]

|_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.WeightCalculatorWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]

|_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.reactive.server.MetricsWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]

|_ checkpoint ⇢ HTTP GET "/images/test/all" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
```

Here is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  react-front:
    image: reactimage:latest
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    profiles:
      - docker
    depends_on:
      - gateway-service
  registry:
    image: registryimage:latest
    ports:
      - 8084:8084
    profiles:
      - docker
    environment:
      - "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker"
  gateway-service:
    image: gatewayimage:latest
    container_name: gatewaycontainer
    environment:
      - JAVA_OPTS=
        -DEUREKA_SERVER=http://registry:8084/eureka
      - "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker"
    ports:
      - 9191:9191
    depends_on:
      - registry
    profiles:
      - docker
  db:
    container_name: dbcontainer
    image: 'mysql/mysql-server:5.7'
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: nasausers
      MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
    volumes:
      - ./login-service/InsertData:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    ports:
      - '3301:3306'
    restart: always
    profiles:
      - docker
  login-service:
    image: loginimage:latest
    environment:
      - JAVA_OPTS=-DEUREKA_SERVER=http://registry:8084/eureka
      - "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker"
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
    depends_on:
      - db
      - registry
    profiles:
      - docker
  images-service:
    image: imagesimage:latest
    environment:
      - JAVA_OPTS=-DEUREKA_SERVER=http://registry:8084/eureka
      - "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker"
    ports:
      - 9001:9001
    depends_on:
      - registry
    profiles:
      - docker
```

I also have a discovery service that my gateway uses to find the images service, it is called registry-service in the docker-compose. Using postman to send a get request to localhost:9001/images/test, works, but when i try through the gateway at localhost:9191/images/test it gives me 500 status error.

Comment: Is the gateway forwarding the request to the backend, or sending an HTTP redirect to the client?  How does it know where the various backend services are?  (The error message implies to me that the `images-service` is registering itself as `127.0.0.1:9001` to the gateway, but the gateway needs to use the Compose service name `images-service` to forward to it.)

Comment: The gateway is using the name that the images-service is registering in the eureka service. By going into my eureka server localhost i can see all of my microservices are registering correctly. The gateway is redirecting to images-service like this: - id: IMAGES-SERVICE
          uri: lb://IMAGES-SERVICE
          predicates:
            - Path=/images/**

Answer (score 3):

I actually solved it by using

```
 instance:
    preferIpAddress: true
```

on the microservices that connect to eureka